# Let N and M be natural numbers. Find the sum of the last M digits of the number N

Tags: javascript

I dont have any idea how to sovle it :

```
const SumOfNum = (N,M)=>{
         var res = N.toString().split('');
         var arr = res.[length-1]
        return N*arr
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using reduce:

```js
const sumLastDigits = (n, m) => {
  const str = n.toString()
  const last = str.slice(str.length - m)
  return Array.from(last).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + Number(curr), 0)
}

console.log(
  sumLastDigits(1234, 2)
)
```

Comment: You can also use `str.slice(-m)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a commented example:

```js
function myFunction(n, m) {
  // CONVERT n TO STRING AND SPLIT INTO AN ARRAY OF CHARACTERS.
  const arr = [...n.toString()];
  
  const length = arr.length;
  
  const start = length - 1;
  const end = start - m;
  
  let count = 0;
  
  // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY FROM THE END.
  for (let i = start; i > end; i--) {
    // CONVERT CHARACTER TO INTEGER AND SUM.
    count += parseInt(arr[i]);
  }
  
  return count;
}

console.log(myFunction(54321, 1)); // 1
console.log(myFunction(54321, 2)); // 3
console.log(myFunction(54321, 3)); // 6
console.log(myFunction(54321, 4)); // 10
console.log(myFunction(54321, 5)); // 15
```